# BeanCreationException while using two instances of Session factories

Tags: java, spring, sessionfactory

I have created two transaction managers(one for READ requests and another for READ-WRITE requests) and two session factories for the same.

Important snippets are as follows:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManagerRead"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    <qualifier value="READ"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManagerWrite"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="Session1" />
     <qualifier value="WRITE"/>
</bean>

<bean id="AbstractSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
.....
....
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="SessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    parent="AbstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
.........
.........
</props>
</property>
</bean>



<bean id="SessionFactory1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    parent="AbstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
.........
.........
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```

The moment I am trying to create a bean for DAO, like:

```
<bean id="configurationDAO" class="com.amazon.im.dao.hibernate.ConfigurationDAOImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I am getting `BeanCreationException` with following error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.amazon.im.dao.hibernate.GenericDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [SessionFactory, SessionFactory1]

I cannot use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` because I want to use "annotatedClasses" property.

Any pointers on why is it happening?
Is there anything missing from my side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like the `sessionFactory` property of your `GenericDAOImpl` class (which I assume is the superclass of `ConfigurationDAOImpl`?) is annotated with `@Autowired`. This won't work because it has two session factories to choose from.  Also, you're manually injecting the correct session factory using `<property>`, so the `@Autowired` isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
Apart from this, do I need to put all transaction managers in <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="ManagerName"/> ?
Because I am getting  -  "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here".

Comment: @tyro: You can specify a particular tx manager in `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="..>"/>`, but when you have multiple tx managers then annotation-driven transactions aren't very useful, since all annotations will use the same tx manager. If you need multiple tx managers, then programmatic transactions are probably a better bet, although they're not pretty: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic

Comment: @skaffman I think Transactional annotation supports multiple txn managers using @Transactional("Tx_Manager_Name") . Can we not use this ?

Comment: @AravindA: Yes, that works, but only if any given method will only ever be invoked by one tx manager.

Answer (score 0):

Also check for the autowire and default-autowire for "byType" in your Spring definitions , There's for to be an autowiring happening somewhere..